# How do I get the top-level directories of a bucket in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I list of the common prefixes for the objects in my bucket?

If I use `ListObjects`, I am able to retrieve objects.  I can see there's a common prefix called 2017:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
    var listObjectsResponse = client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucket,
        Prefix = "2",
        Delimiter = "",
    });

    // Prints: 2017/11/08/<omitted>.json
    Console.WriteLine(listObjectsResponse.S3Objects.First().Key);        
}
```

However if I set `Delimiter`, nothing is returned:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
    var listObjectsResponse = client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucket,
        Prefix = "2",
        Delimiter = "/",
    });

    // Prints: 0
    Console.WriteLine(listObjectsResponse.S3Objects.Count);      
}
```

How do I get the common prefixes like 2017 to be returned?

I've tried looking at the documentation and it just says to use prefix and delimiter, but that's not working.

Comment: There are no directories in S3, only object names. You can fake a directory structure by putting slashes in object names but they are not actually directories.

Comment: Is your question actually "How do I list of the common prefixes for the objects in my bucket?"

Comment: @bhspencer Thanks for the reply!! Yes, that was my question

Comment: @bhspencer I figured it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there's a `CommonPrefixes` property on `ListObjectsResponse`.

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
    var listObjectsResponse = client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucket,
        Prefix = "2",
        Delimiter = "/",
    });

    // Prints: 2017
    Console.WriteLine(listObjectsResponse.CommonPrefixes[0]);     
}
```